# jQuery .load() function only works once

Tags: jquery, load, gallery

This is frustrating to no end - especially since the very same code has worked right on other pages!

Basically, I'm trying to get images to load inside a container div for portfolio:

```
<div class="slide" id="slide2" data-slide="2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div class="container clearfix">

        <div id="content" class="grid_12">
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <h2>A sampling of my work.</h2>

            <div id="portfolio">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The portfolio gallery is found in an external page, as well as are the individual images, such as this:

```
<html>

<img src="images/litnetwork.jpg" />

<a href="#"><span id="back" style="color: white;">Go Back</span></a>

<h3>Online Literature Network</h3>

<p><i>A site proposal to remake Online Literature's current website, using more of an open feel and organic text.</i></p>

</html>
```

And here's the javascript for the load function:

```
$(function() {

var   portfolio     = $('#portfolio')
     , main        = $('main.html')
     , images      = $('#images')
     , back        = $('#back')
     , scotty      = $('#images #scotty')
     , litnetwork  = $('#images #litnetwork');

showSet('main.html');

portfolio.on('click', litnetwork, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showSet('litnetwork.html');
    });

portfolio.on('click', scotty, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showSet('scotty.html');
    });



portfolio.on('click', back, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showSet('main.html');
    });

function showSet(show) {
    portfolio.load(show);
    }

});
```

It only loads once, from time to time, and the "Go Back" link works, but then it stops working.

Help!

Here's the website: [Portfolio Site](http://www.justinfowlerdesign.com/coolkitten/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
portfolio.on('click', litnetwork, function(e){
```

`litenetwork` needs to be a string selector, not a jquery object.

```
litnetwork  = '#images #litnetwork'
```

the same is true for the rest of your delegated event handlers.

Comment: Wow! Presto, it works! Thanks! :D

(Why is that, btw?)

Comment: It's just invalid syntax, which makes it work in an unexpected way.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you again! I should've asked this hours ago. :B